# How to get id from an innerHTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written the following function.
        There are controls inside Table which is inside a div.
        I need to print id of all the controls

```
  function getID() {
        debugger;
        var ids = [];
        var children = document.getElementById("divAlarmSection").children;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {

            ids.push(children[i].id);
            var table = document.getElementById(children[i].id);
            var rows = table.rows;
            for (i = 0, n = rows.length; i < n; ++i) {
                var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

                for (var x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
                    if (cells[x].length != 0) {
                        alert(cells[x].innerHTML);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the html in your question? And could you give an example of your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .getElementsByTagName("*") on cells[x] and access 'ID' property of the result. So your last 'for' loop becomes:

```
var elements = cells[x].getElementsByTagName("*")
for(var len=0;len<elements.length;len++)
       console.log(elements[len].id);
```

Also, if you know the inner structure of each 's and its consistent, you can look for that element in .getElementsByTagName()